# Draft.js - How to apply custom entity to current selection only?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm using a sample code found [here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/link/link.html) to implement a custom entity for links.

**What is the current behavior?**

Select a portion of text, and create a link. Then keep typing after the link is created, and the editor will mark all characters you type in as a part of the link.

**What is the expected behavior?**

The link should be created for the current selection only. When you type more characters after creating a link, they should be plain text, not a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `IMMUTABLE` entity.

https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-entities.html#mutability